# Cloudera CDH 5.13 - is it possible to run spark 2.x with Yarn mode?

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, cloudera-manager

Team,

Installed CDH 5.13 version on my local computer and doing upgrade from spark 1.6 to spark 2.0. is it possible to do run spark application using yarn mode. Please confirm .  or it will work as standalone mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Both modes are supported.

From CDH 6.x Stand Alone is no longer supported.

Comment: I tried in my CDH version (Cloudera Expression 5.13.0).. Getting bellow exception while adding 
* The CSD version (2.2.0.cloudera2) is not compatible with the current
* Spark 2 version (). Either update your CSD or      
* make sure you have the correct Spark version installed and       
* activated.                                                       
**********

Comment: Add this jar : SPARK2_ON_YARN-2.2.0.cloudera2.jar . Am i added right jar ..? if not can you please suggest me right jar to download

Comment: Your question was if supported. These are different questions. If for learning purposes use a VM with 2.x already installed.

Comment: @thebluephantom - I recently downloaded quickstart VM of Cloudera (5.13). But I didn't find Spark 2 already present in it. I had to manually install it using the CSD of Spark2

Comment: That’s why I use mapr.

Answer (score 2):

YARN supports stand alone mode and cluster mode. I have used both of them and they work fine on Cloudera 5.11 + Spark2 setup.